# Syntax error trying to insert row when using "show" as field name

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a table:

```
up_rel

> |--id--|--uid--|--pid--|--show--|
```

i am doing this insert sequence:

```
 $icat_sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO product_category (name, parent) VALUES(:name, :parent)");
    $icat_sth->bindParam(':name', $post['cat_name']);
    $icat_sth->bindParam(':parent', $post['parent_category']);
    $icat_sth->execute();
    $pid = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    $rel_sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO up_rel (uid, pid, show) VALUES(:uid, :pid, :show)");
    $rel_sth->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
    $rel_sth->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
    $rel_sth->bindParam(':show', '1');
    $rel_sth->execute();
    echo $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

First insert to product category goes smooth but next insert returns an error:

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'show) VALUES(?, ?, ?)' at line 1

If i remove show from the insert it works.

I have tried putting the one in the values `(:uid, :pid, 1)`
and in the bind I have quoted it and not.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: $uid is set earlier in the script.. $pid is set from the last insert Id of the first insert. If i remove show, it works.. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Show` is a reserved word in MySQL, so I assume that's the error you're seeing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html.

Per @Burhan Khalid's contribution (which is a good option if you can't rename the field):

> To escape reserved words, use back ticks  ``.

And @newfurniturey has a more useful reference for reserved words:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: You should add to your answer that to escape reserved words, use back ticks ` `

Comment: Also, a link to the MySQL Reserved Words page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thanks the follow-up, guys - both make this answer much more useful. Appreciated.